# Excel Dir returns unexpected null

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write what I thought would be a simple routine to take all the Excel sheets in a directory and copy them to tabs in a master sheet. Here's what I'm trying:

```
Sub GetSheets()
      myPath = "C:\Users\Brian.Scott\Documents\2017_INVENTORY\TestInv"
      Filename = Dir(myPath)
      MsgBox (Filename)
    Do While Filename <> ""
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
      For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      Next Sheet
      Workbooks(Filename).Close
      Filename = Dir()
    Loop
  End Sub
```

I put in the MsgBox when nothing was happening. It returns a null. myPath returns the correct name - which I copied and pasted from explorer to avoid spelling errors. I only have excel files in the directory, so I'm not error checking. This is a one-off need, but there are over 200 files in the directory, so I figured I could spend a little time on the code.
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty green with this.

Comment: Did you forget a file wildcard? - `"C:\Users\Brian.Scott\Documents\2017_INVENTORY\TestInv\*.XLS*"`

Comment: You will also need a backslash between the myPath and Filename.

Comment: Can you try `Dir(myPath, vbDirectory)` or `Dir()`

Comment: For the record, `Null` isn't `vbNullString` or `""`. `Null` is a very special value that you're unlikely to ever need or even come across in VBA code written against the Excel object model.

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed that problem. Here's my altered code:Sub GetSheets()
myPath = "C:\Users\Brian.Scott\Documents\2017_INVENTORY\TestInv\*.xls*"
myFilename = Dir(myPath)

  Do While myFilename <> ""
  MsgBox (myPath & "\" & myFilename)
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & "\" & myFilename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(myFilename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub    However, I get a message that "Method open failed

Comment: Post an answer, don't answer in comments ;-)

Comment: @B_Scott - you do not need the second `*` in `*.xls*‌`. Just `*.xls` is enough.

Comment: The files are xlsx that was the reason for the second *

Comment: Also the `Workbooks.Open` method *returns an object reference to the workbook object* that was just opened - you should keep that reference in a `Workbook` variable, e.g. `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)`, and then you work against that `wb` variable instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. This means you can do `wb.Close` instead of fetching that object from the `Workbooks` collection every time... and here I am, answering in comments...

Comment: Sorry - new here - I'm not seeing how to "Post" and answer

Comment: No problem, see below - and feel free to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare all your variables - specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and then declare every single variable you use until the code compiles again. Not doing that is only asking for trouble; VBA will happily compile and run a typo, and debugging that isn't fun at all. Use Option Explicit. Always.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetSheets()
    Const myPath As String = "C:\Users\Brian.Scott\Documents\2017_INVENTORY\"
    Const myFilter As String = "TestInv*.xls?"

    Dim myFilename As String
    myFilename = Dir(myPath & myFilter)

    Do While myFilename <> vbNullString
        MsgBox myFilename
        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
            Dim sh As Worksheet
            For Each sh In .Worksheets
                sh.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Next
            .Close
        End With
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Notice that `With` block - it's holding a reference to the `Workbook` object that the `Workbooks.Open` function returns, so you can do `.Worksheets` and `.Close` against it, without needing to code against `ActiveWorkbook`, and without needing to re-fetch that exact same object reference from the `Workbooks` collection at every iteration.

Your `myPath` contains a path, yes, but also wildcards, and I doubt this would work as expected:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Brian.Scott\Documents\2017_INVENTORY\TestInv*.xls?\TestInv42.xlsx"
```

That's why I split the `myPath` string into a *path* and a *filter*: you supply the *filter* to the `Dir` function, and supply the `Workbooks.Open` function with the *path* with the file name that `Dir` returned.

Comment: I may a few minor modifications (I think my explanation was wanting) and it works like a charm! I need to rename the tabs - I can use a specific cell for the name. Should I do that on the way in, or after I get them in the master sheet?

Comment: You can do it any way you want to - just as long as you never end up with 2 sheets with the same name, everything should go well. I'd try to do it in the loop body. I think `sh.Copy` will activate the created sheet, so you'd go `ActiveSheet.Name = whateverYouMakeItBe`

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting all the sheets in the directory - only 4 out 6

Comment: Check your filter, compare to the missing file names, adjust accordingly. If they look the same, watch for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: I set the filter to *.xls? which I assume will grab everything. The only difference in the names is a leading date. "1-3-2017 Inventory" is not getting used but "1-9-2017 Inventory" is being picked up

Comment: If you can, use a folder that only contains the files you need, and go with `*.*` for a filter =)

Comment: It appears to only load 4 sheets no matter how many are in the directory

Comment: I changed the filter - still only 4 files processed

Comment: Without a run-time error, that makes little sense. Are you silencing errors with `On Error Resume Next` by any chance?

Comment: No not silencing anything. It only does 4 no matter how many are in the directory

Comment: Make a new question, share your code *and* the expected filenames. Something isn't adding up.

Comment: Sorry - ignore my ineptitude! All is working great. Operator error! Thanks VERY much for all your help!